# highcharts - Not able to switch between bar to column or vice versa graph type in drilldown

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts, drilldown

Why highcharts is not switching between bar to column or column to bar when you go to drilldown. If I use for example column or bar in main series and pie in drilldown it's able to draw drilldown in pie. But if I put column in main series and put bar in drilldown, it still draws drilldown in column.
You can see this problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/q7Ss6/

Main chart type can be edited in 6th row of javascript:

```
    ....
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    ....
```

drilldown type can be added in drilldown series. e.g.

```
    .....
    name: 'Opera',
            id: 'Opera',
            type: 'column',
    .....
```

Comment: In Highcharts bar and column types are almost the same. The difference between them is that bar have inverted xAxis and yAxis. In HC5 (future Highcharts release) it will be possible to dynamically invert your axes.

Comment: Can we invert axis when user goes to drilldown? All I want is to have bar chart in main series and column in drilldown chart.

Comment: Unfortunately right now I think that the only way to do that is to destroy your chart and make new one.

Comment: Yes that I know. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In line 101 you explicit set a pie chart
That is your code:

```
'name': drilldown.name,
'categories': drilldown.categories,
'data': drilldown.data,
'color': drilldown.color,
'type': 'pie'
```

You set '**pie**' explicitly.